# Python mailer-0.7: Permission denied error

Tags: email, python-2.7

I am trying to install Python mailer-0.7 and I am getting a permission error.  I'm no Mac OS expert.  Can anyone please give simple instructions to fix.

Thanks

Error message is as follows

```
 error: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mailer.py: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha - i added "sudo" at beginning of script and it installed.